# Reformat Varchar(6) into Time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a column with "Time" as the values, but it is brought over as varchar(6) type.
Is there a good way to convert this to HH:MM:SS format?
Example data (TimeField) and what I want (NewTime), or could just be the hour (HourOnly)

```
TimeField      NewTime    HourOnly
 102157       10:21:57     10 am
 071740       07:17:40     7 am
 000602       00:06:02     12 am
 225058       22:50:58     10 pm
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You use string functions to stuff the colons into the values and then cast to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use string functions and [`timefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
timefromparts(left(timefield, 2), substring(timefield, 3, 2), right(timefield, 2))
```

If you just want the hour component, that's even simpler:

```
left(timefield, 2)                -- as a string
cast(left(timefield, 2) as int)   -- as an integer
```